# Rails 4 render a xml layout from an Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, layout, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller that should not use the regular layout of the application but render an xml as follows.

Usually from any action it uses the default layout and wraps it around the view of the action which i do not want in this case but to just render the following as xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>     
<playtext quality="best">Hello World</playtext>     
</response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to use a specific layout you can put a conditional in your application.html.erb file. If the controller name equals that specific controller you render the xml provided else you render the default layout.